# Want to install gazebo5 but has ROS indigo installed

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to install Gazebo5. But I have already installed ROS indigo which provides Gazebo2 instead. I think this is because Gazebo2 works well with ROS indigo(am I right?).So if I want to install Gazebo5 I have to remove Gazebo2. Now the problem is I am not sure whether I can use Gazebo5 to communicate with ROS or not? Specifically, I want to use the ROS message mechanism in Gazebo5 as well, does ROS indigo support Gazebo 5?

Thanks for any suggestion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8159/want-to-install-gazebo5-but-has-ros-indigo-installed./) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In order to have Gazebo5 with ROS Indigo you have to uninstall first the gazebo2 packages that ROS Indigo installed (ros-indigo-gazebo-*)

Then add the osrf repositories to your Linux package manager and follow the command provided by Jose Luis Rivero [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7999/gazebo5-ros-packages/)

I'm using Gazebo5 with ROS and it works fine. When I installed it, I remember there was one of the ros-indigo-gazebo5-* packages that was not installed by default.
Just check that all your ros-indigo-gazebo5-* packages are installed.

---

Originally posted by [Ricardo Tellez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1118/ricardo-tellez/) with karma: 78 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2